# Increase size of window resize drag area

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

Not sure if this is a Ubuntu specific question or something specific to the DE I am using (MATE).

Is there any way to increase the area to drag-resize windows on the desktop?
This is the spot in the lower right of each desktop window.
When you hover over you see the 'drag-resize' icon with a diagonal arrow.
It can be very difficult to precisely select.

Comment: Instead of selecting the resize area, you may right-click on the top window bar and select "resize".

Comment: ok cool, didn't know this. actually more functional

Comment: In Unity, you can press Alt+F8 to resize the window. I don't know if it's the same in MATE.

Answer (score 5):

Others have some good workarounds for the tiny area that gives you the resize handles. Another thing that should work is:
Holding Alt, click and drag with the right mouse button from anywhere inside the window, you will be in resize mode as if you were grabbing the nearest corner.

Comment: This doesn't work for me I'm using gnome and gnome terminal.